# Why webpack returns an empty object when requiring its output?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to bundle my project and then require the bundled minified output.
My index.js file looks like this:

```
const browserHost = require('./hosts/browserHost')
const workerHost = require('./hosts/workerHost')
module.exports = {
    initBrowserHost: options => browserHost.init(options),
    initWorkerHost: options => workerHost.init(options)
}
```

When requiring it I have my two init functions. When I'm bundling my project with `webpack` and requiring `index.min.js`, I have an empty object.
Webpack config:

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [
                    /node_modules/,
                    /\.unit\.js$/
                ],
                use: ['babel-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        dns: 'empty'
    },
    target: 'node',
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.min.js'
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                parallel: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    ecma: 6
                }
            })
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you look at the generated file? Maybe disable minification.

Comment: Where are you requiring the `index.js`, in one of the modules that it depends on?

Comment: @Bergi no, I require it in tests and other repository (npm module)

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: @RobertMolina Hey, I just removed everything and at the moment running first `babel` and then webpack over the generated files. `.webpack.config` uses only `mode`, `entry` and `output` properties. Works, but I still didn't figure out why didn't it work that way ^

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Yinon

Comment: side-note: from: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin : `Default number of concurrent runs: os.cpus().length - 1` so there is no need to specify it. it is even better to not specify it due to it's a dynamic value that is determined by the amount of your CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you build a library for others to use from node_modules, you need to tell webpack that you want to support `umd` (in simple words, you want to let your consumers use it from `require(yinon_lib)` or import .. from 'yinon_lib'`).

The way to do that is:

```
output: {
      ...
      libraryTarget: 'umd', 
    },
```

More information:

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/

Example:

https://github.com/stavalfi/lerna-yarn-workspaces-example/tree/master/packages/x-core